# Regex not matching numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse through math within strings. It works for x*y but not `x*y*z`. I think it has to do with one is a string while the other is a number. But I can't find a way to get around it.

Here is my code:

```
var reMD = /(\d+) *[\*|\/] *(\d+)/g
var str = '17 * 13 * 4';
var ex;
runWhile();

function runWhile() {
   var ex = reMD.exec(str);
   if (ex !== null) {
     if (ex.index === reMD.lastIndex) {
       reMD.lastIndex++;
     }
     if (ex[0].indexOf('*') !== -1) {
       var rep = parseInt(ex[1]) * parseInt(ex[2])
     } else {
       var rep = parseInt(ex[1]) / parseInt(ex[2])
     }
     var rep = rep.toString()
     str = str.replace(ex[0], rep)
     if (reMD.exec(str) !== null) {
       runWhile()
     }
   }
}
alert(str)
```

The alert sends back `221 * 4` but it should come back as `884`. How would I fix this?

Comment: How would I fix this so it sees it as `221 *4` the second time `exec()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you remove the `g` flag from your regex, because then each time you call `.exec()` it will start afresh as explained [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). You can also remove the code that is messing with `reMD.lastIndex`.

(With the `g` flag, it tries to match from the index of where the previous match ended, but you are trying to match against a new string.)

Note also that you could change your regex to match the operator too, rather than using `indexOf()`, and you don't really need to call `parseInt()` because the `*` and `/` operators will coerce their operands to numbers:

```js
var reMD = /(\d+) *([\*|\/]) *(\d+)/
var str = '17 * 13 / 4';  // note I've change the input to demostrate * and /
runWhile();

function runWhile() {
   var ex = reMD.exec(str);
   if (ex !== null) {
     if (ex[2]==="*") {
       var rep = ex[1] * ex[3]
     } else {
       var rep = ex[1] / ex[3]
     }
     rep = rep.toString()
     str = str.replace(ex[0], rep)
     if (reMD.exec(str) !== null) {
       runWhile()
     }
   }
}
console.log(str)
```

(Note: it's still a little bit untidy for the function to be using and modifying variables defined outside the function, but I'll leave any further tidy-up as an exercise for the reader...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will suffice for your project but it works

```
'17 * 13 * 4'.replace(/(\d+)( *[\*|\/] *(\d+))*/g, eval)
```